# Combining text and an image into one "entity"

Tags: javascript, html, dojo, rich-text-editor

I need some assistance while working with a rich text editor (specifically the Dojo Editor dijit), but this question should apply to all RTE's.

I am seeking a way (via HTML/JS/etc, whatever works in a text editor..) to combine some text and an image, in such a way that they can be manipulated as 1 entity. So I should be able to, for instance, select the entity as a whole, and cut/paste it elsewhere in the textbox, or delete it with a single key press, etc.

I am not sure what features text editors do and don't support, but is there a feature that is equivalent to a container/wrapper/textbox, which combines the text and image into 1 single entity?

Thanks

Comment: Can you not just wrap it in another Element? Then use events bound to that parent element...?

Comment: Can't you just use `_widigetBase` and `_templateMixin` to create a widget? Then it'll be considered one entity on your HTML code (i.e. `<div data-dojo-type="my.Widget"></div>`

Comment: Would an HTML5 `<figure>` element not work for you?

Answer (score 0):

First save image, and then add text on the image using photo editing software or word art or microsoft powerpoint. (You can try whatever.) Then save the image again with the text. Then you can use the image and text whole as a single entity. But the issue is you can't change the text dynamically on your webpage. It will become static.